# Stopping a started script in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this code

```
var process = childProcess.fork(scriptPath, [args[0], args[1], args[2]]);

runScript('index.js', function (err) {
    if (err) console.log("error"); 
}
```

I want to stop it after starting it, how can I do that? Is a part of a discord bot, when i type `!start + argv` it starts a script with `node index.js + argv` but how can i stop it? first argv is session id. I tried to do

```
if command = !stop <session id> then return, process.exit
```

but didn't worked.
`client.on('message', msg => { if (msg.content === 'stop') { msg.reply('stopping...'); return; //process.exit(1); } });` this is what i tried.

Comment: The only way to stop a function is for it to encounter an error or a `return` statement.

Comment: i tried but it doesn't stop the script which i started, i tried to do when someone type "!stop" to return it but it doesn't stop it.

Comment: You'll need to post the code that you've tried.

Comment: client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'stop') {
    msg.reply('stopping...');
 return;
 //process.exit(1);
  }
});
this is what i tried.

Comment: No, please edit your QUESTION and include the complete code that you've tried.

Comment: did it, thanks, i'm new there